# mplcursors crash on setting "annotation_positions"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mplcursors

I found some issue, maybe a bug in `mplcursors` library. Because already done the reproducable code, put this below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 30
n = [int(i) for i in range(0,N)]
x = np.random.random(N)*10
y = np.random.random(N)*10
z = np.random.random(N)*10

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array([n, x, y, z]).T, columns = ['id', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False, facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='green', dpi=200, figsize=(8,5))    
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

points = ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, s=5, marker='o', edgecolor='black', linewidth=.5)

def getInfo(sel):
     n,x,y,z = df.loc[sel, ['id', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]
     
     row = "Point: " + str(n) + "\n" + str(x) + ", \n" + str(y) + ", \n" + str(z)
     return row

ap = [{'horizontalalignment': 'left', 'verticalalignment': 'top', 'anncoords': 'offset points'}] #, 'position': (8, -8)}]
mc = mplcursors.cursor(points, hover=2, annotation_positions=ap)
mc.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text( getInfo(sel.index) ))
mc.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.get_bbox_patch().set(fc="palegreen", alpha=0.75))    

plt.show()
```

The error message is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 196, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplcursors\_mplcursors.py", line 567, in _on_hover_motion_notify
    self._on_select_event(event)
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplcursors\_mplcursors.py", line 615, in _on_select_event
    self.add_selection(pi)
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplcursors\_mplcursors.py", line 412, in add_selection
    bbox = ann.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 2403, in get_window_extent
    bboxes.append(self.arrow_patch.get_window_extent())
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 609, in get_window_extent
    return self.get_path().get_extents(self.get_transform())
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 4218, in get_path
    _path, fillable = self.get_path_in_displaycoord()
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 4238, in get_path_in_displaycoord
    shrinkB=self.shrinkB * dpi_cor
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 2775, in __call__
    clipped_path = self._clip(path, patchA, patchB)
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 2728, in _clip
    left, right = split_path_inout(path, insideA)
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\bezier.py", line 274, in split_path_inout
    ctl_points, command = next(path_iter)
StopIteration
```

The issue is in the line:

```
ap = [{'horizontalalignment': 'left', 'verticalalignment': 'top',
       'anncoords': 'offset points'}] #, 'position': (8, -8)}]
```

Everything works if I either skip the `ap` variable, or add `position` variable to the list. No other way round. The drawback for this is that I can't justify the text without `ap` and the position of hover is not selecting automatically - when the `ap` is assigned.

If anyone knows the solution to have justification without manually positioning the hoverbox please answer, however it's minor issue at the end.

Comment: It seems that an annotation with `'horizontalalignment': 'left'` will always be placed to the right of the anchor point.  And, similarly, `'verticalalignment': 'top'` will always be placed below the anchor point.  This is independent of mplcursors. What you want to achieve (i.e. left align when the text is at the left of the anchor), doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: Yes, I think so, but it's not very important. At least I've replaced my `ap` line with `mc.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set(fontsize=5, ha="left", va="center", **hfont))` and I can adjust text to one side, so it's not flowing between margins.